# Laravel/Ajax passing data to controller: data is null

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.8

I am trying to pass two variables to my controller using ajax. There are no errors but the data is null when I get it in the controller.

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/donate/select-card', 'CardController@chooseCard')->name('select-card');
```

**CardController.php**

```
public function chooseCard()
{
  $from = Input::get("fromAmount");
  // $to = $request->input('toAmount');
  dd($from);
}
```

> 'null' is the output here

**Script.js**

```
fromAmount = $(this).find('p span:nth-child(1)').text().split("₹ ")[1];
toAmount = $(this).find('p span:nth-child(2)').text().split("₹ ")[1];
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
     url: '/donate/select-card',
     data:  { fromAmount : fromAmount, toAmount : toAmount }
});
```

What I want is to have the fromAmount & toAmount in my controller.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit-1**

This is the ajax data from network:

[image]

Comment: Watch the Network tab of your browser console when it requests, and make sure that the data is being sent properly. If not, then you'll need to double-check your fromAmount/toAmount values inside of your script.js.

Comment: @aynber I've added the screenshot of the Network tab in the console.

Comment: Try changing the Controller code like so, `public function chooseCard(Request $request) {  dd($request->all());  }`. What output do you get?

Comment: @linuxartisan Did it and the got '[ ]' as output

Comment: What about the commented line in **CardController**, `$to = $request->input('toAmount');` ? Is that also giving `null`?

Comment: @linuxartisan yes